# How to insert values into a table BASED on sum values of columns in other tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best way to do this using Oracle SQL Developer?

I need to check 14 day (two weeks mon_wk_1, tue_wk_2 etc.. columns) in table Primary to see if there are any hours indicated on any day of the week, if there are, then insert the day’s hour values into the corresponding field in the load_table.

If there are no hours on any days in the primary table, then check 14 day columns in the Secondary table to see if there are any hours, if there are then use the secondary table’s values to insert into the load_table.  If neither the primary nor secondary tables show any hours for these two weeks, then use the values for the client from a default record in a default table.

I was thinking of summing the days and then if sum >0 use primary table values for the insert, If some <0 use, Not sure how to set up if it needs to use Default values.  Is there a better way to do this

Something like this:

```
BEGIN
IF
SELECT (SUM   
        (NVL(MON_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(TUE_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(WED_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(THUR_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(FRI_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(SAT_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(SUN_HRS_1,0) +
        NVL(MON_HRS_2,0) +
        NVL(TUE_HRS_2,0) +
        NVL(WED_HRS_2,0) +
        NVL(THUR_HRS_2,0) +
        NVL(FRI_HRS_2,0) +
        NVL(SAT_HRS_2,0) +
        NVL(SUN_HRS_2,0)) AS TOTAL
FROM   PRIMARY_TABLE PT
                   JOIN EMPLOYEE E
                                ON PT.CLIENT_ID = E.CLIENT_ID
                                AND PT.EE_ID = E.EE_ID
WHERE CLIENT_ID = 'FOOBAR') >0
THEN
INSERT INTO LOAD_TABLE
        SELECT
        E.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
        E.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
        E.EE_ID,
  PT.NVL(MON_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(TUE_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(WED_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(THUR_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(FRI_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(SAT_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(SUN_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(MON_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(TUE_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(WED_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(THUR_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(FRI_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(SAT_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(SUN_HRS_2,0),
                DATE(SYSDATE),              
                1 AS USER_ID
                FROM   PRIMARY_TABLE PT
                                 JOIN EMPLOYEE E
                                  ON PT.CLIENT_ID = E.CLIENT_ID
                                  AND PT.EE_ID = E.EE_ID
        WHERE CLIENT_ID = 'FOOBAR');
ELSE
INSERT INTO LOAD_TABLE
                (
                SELECT
                E.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
                E.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
                E.EE_ID,
                PT.NVL(MON_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(TUE_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(WED_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(THUR_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(FRI_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(SAT_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(SUN_HRS_1,0),
        PT.NVL(MON_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(TUE_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(WED_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(THUR_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(FRI_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(SAT_HRS_2,0),
        PT.NVL(SUN_HRS_2,0),
                DATE(SYSDATE),              
                1 AS USER_ID
                FROM   SECONDAY_TABLE PT
                                 JOIN EMPLOYEE E
                                  ON PT.CLIENT_ID = E.CLIENT_ID
                                  AND PT.EE_ID = E.EE_ID
        WHERE CLIENT_ID = 'FOOBAR'
                );
END IF;
END;
```

---

DATA SOURCE TABLES:

primary table

```
EE_ID   VARCHAR2,
CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
MON_HRS_1 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_1 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_1 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_1 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_1 NUMBER,
MON_HRS_2 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_2 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_2 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_2 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_2 NUMBER,
ACTUAL_HRS_WK NUMBER,
COMMENTS VARCHAR2
```

SECONDARY TABLE

```
EE_ID   VARCHAR2,
CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
SCHEDULE_ID VARCHAR2
MON_HRS_1 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_1 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_1 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_1 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_1 NUMBER,
MON_HRS_2 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_2 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_2 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_2 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_2 NUMBER,
ACTUAL_HRS_WK NUMBER,
COMMENTS VARCHAR2
```

Client_default

```
CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
MON_HRS_1 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_1 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_1 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_1 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_1 NUMBER,
MON_HRS_2 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_2 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_2 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_2 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_2 NUMBER,
ACTUAL_HRS_WK NUMBER
```

Load_table

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2,
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER NUMBER,
EE_ID VARCHAR VARCHAR2,
MON_HRS_1 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_1 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_1 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_1 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_1 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_1 NUMBER,
MON_HRS_2 NUMBER,
TUE_HRS_2 NUMBER,
WED_HRS_2 NUMBER,
THUR_HRS_2 NUMBER,
FRI_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SAT_HRS_2 NUMBER,
SUN_HRS_2 NUMBER,
CREATE_DATE DATETIME,
USER_ID VARCHAR2
```

EMPLOYEE_TABLE

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME,
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
EE_ID,
DEPARTMENT,
SSN
```

Comment: *If possible*, could you please describe your table structures?

Comment: Hello abhi!  I've added the data source tables at the bottom.  Hope it helps.  Thanks!  :D

Comment: Answered my own question abhi.  Thank you!!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this.  I basically used math to add up the hours of the 14 days and joined the result set via a subquery.  Then used a Case statement and a nested case statement in my SELECT to choose where the week day values to set would come from.

Hate having to join a table more than once, but this seems to work best for what I needed it to do.

At a high levle it looks something like this:

`SELECT 
    CLIENT_ID,
    CASE WHEN PT_WK_HRS.TOTAL > 0 THEN
    CASE WHEN SEC_WK_HRS.TOTAL >0 THEN ST.MON_HRS_1
    ELSE CD.MON_HRS_1
    END
    ELSE PT.MON_HRS_1
    END AS WS_MON_HRS_1,
    CASE WHEN PT_WK_HRS.TOTAL > 0 THEN
    CASE WHEN SEC_WK_HRS.TOTAL >0 THEN ST.TUE_HRS_1
    ELSE CD.TUE_HRS_1
    END
    ELSE PT.TUE_HRS_1
    END AS WS_TUE_HRS_1 ----AND SO ON FOR EACH DAY OF THE WEEK

    FROM PRIMARY TABLE PT 
    JOIN 
    (SELECT  PT.CLIENT_ID. 
    SUM (NVL(MON_HRS_1,0) + NVL(TUE_HRS_1,0) + NVL(WED_HRS_1,0) + NVL(THUR_HRS_1,0) + NVL(FRI_HRS_1,0) +
    NVL(SAT_HRS_1,0) + NVL(SUN_HRS_1,0) + NVL(MON_HRS_2,0) + NVL(TUE_HRS_2,0) + NVL(WED_HRS_2,0) + 
    NVL(THUR_HRS_2,0) + NVL(FRI_HRS_2,0) + NVL(SAT_HRS_2,0) + NVL(SUN_HRS_2,0)) AS TOTAL
    FROM   PRIMARY_TABLE
    GROUP BY CLIENT_ID) AS PT_WK_HRS
    ON PT.CLIENT_ID = PT_WK_HRS. CLIENT_ID
    JOIN SECONDARY_TABLE ST
    ON PT.CLIENT_ID = ST.CLIENT_ID
    JOIN 
    ( SELECT  PT.CLIENT_ID. 
    SUM (NVL(MON_HRS_1,0) + NVL(TUE_HRS_1,0) + NVL(WED_HRS_1,0) + NVL(THUR_HRS_1,0) + NVL(FRI_HRS_1,0) +
    NVL(SAT_HRS_1,0) + NVL(SUN_HRS_1,0) + NVL(MON_HRS_2,0) + NVL(TUE_HRS_2,0) + NVL(WED_HRS_2,0) + 
    NVL(THUR_HRS_2,0) + NVL(FRI_HRS_2,0) + NVL(SAT_HRS_2,0) + NVL(SUN_HRS_2,0)) AS TOTAL
    FROM   SECONDARY_TABLE
    GROUP BY CLIENT_ID) AS SEC_WK_HRS
    ON PT.CLIENT_ID = SEC_WK_HRS.CLIENT_ID
    JOIN CLIENT_DFLT CD
    ON PT.CLIENT_ID = CD.CLIENT_ID`

Comment: Good Work! I am glad that you were able to solve it on your own.